# Drop down list lose its value while post back in asp.net Mvc5 in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

> This is a partial view. while submitting page is refreshed and my drop down value is gone.

```
@{
var pageName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

ScanPaDataBaseApp.SCANHRConn dbConfig = new ScanPaDataBaseApp.SCANHRConn();

    var MySalutList = dbConfig.Codes.ToList();
    var SalutData = from Salut in dbConfig.Codes
                    where Salut.Typ.Trim() == "SALUT"
                    orderby Salut.SDes
                    select Salut;
    SelectList GetSalutList = new SelectList(SalutData, "Cd", "sDes");
    ViewBag.SalutList = GetSalutList;
    @Html.DropDownList("Salutation", ViewBag.SalutList as SelectList, "Select Salut", new { Style = "width:236px; color:#858585;" })
```

Comment: Consider using strongly-typed viewmodel property: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Salutation, ViewBag.SalutList as SelectList, "Select Salut", new { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

Use @Html.DropdownListFor which automatically bind your list to model and you can use it. :)